# filtering a queryset based on another queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model called UserCommunityProfiles Structured as follows

```
class UserCommunityProfile(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    (...)
```

and a model called subscriptions structured :

```
class subscriptions(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='subscriber'
    )
    subscribed_to = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='subscribed_to'
    )
```

and what i am trying to achieve is display the profiles of every user which is not in the query set subscriptions as a subscribed_to and the subscriber is `request.user`

what i did is in the views i did

```
subs = subscriptions.objects.filter(subscriber=request.user)
profiles = UserCommunityProfile.objects.exclude(owner=subs)
```

but i get an error saying `Cannot use QuerySet for "subscriptions": Use a QuerySet for "User".` what should i do ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution:

```
subs=User.objects.filter(subscribed_to__subscriber=request.user).values_list('id')
profiles = UserCommunityProfile.objects.exclude(owner__in=subs)
```

Comment: I think the formatting of the last lines is a bit "weird", can you fix it, so we can see if it is correct and upvote :)

Comment: Sorry for that.I have Formatted code now.
Ask if there's any confusion.

Comment: isn't it possible that there are *multiple* subscriptions where `request.user` is the `subscriber`. By using `.first()` it is possible that the others are *not* taken into account :s.

Comment: If that is the case than you have to do like 
    subs =User.objects.filter(subscribed_to__subscriber=request.user).values_list('id')
    profiles = UserCommunityProfile.objects.exclude(owner__in=subs)

Comment: I think it is probably worth to add this to the answer :)

Comment: Does anybody knows if these lines run one or two SQL request ?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use `QuerySet`s to filter other `QuerySet`s, but as the error here says, you use `owner`s, so that means that it expects to work with a `QuerySet` that wraps `User`s, but here you provide a `QuerySet` containing `Subscriptions`.

We can however use the following query:

```
subs = User.objects.filter(subscribed_to__subscriber=request.user)
profiles = UserCommunityProfile.objects.exclude(owner__in=subs)
```

Furthermore we do *not* need two `QuerySet`s anyway, we can query it like:

```
profiles = UserCommunityProfile.objects.exclude(
    owner__subscribed_to__subscriber=request.user
)
```

This will thus provide a `QuerySet` that contains *all* `UserCommunityProfile`s for which there is *no* `Subscriptions` with the `owner` being the `subscribed_to` and the `subscriber` being the `self.request.user`.

If you "combine" querysets like demonstrated above, then typically this will result in a *single* query. This usually is *more efficient*, since then all processing is done at the database level, and databases are optimized for such tasks.

There can however be some cases where that is *not* the case, for example if one has two disjunct conditions, and each conditions results in a list of (independent) `JOIN`s, then it might be better to rewrite the query with for example a `UNION`. But this is not the case here.